# Making an api call inside looped component creates duplicate requests

Tags: angular, typescript, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm looping through an array of elements `*ngFor="let note of notes"`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let note of notes">
  <div class="cards-grid">
    <notes-card
      [note]="note"
    ></notes-card>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

the notes array looks something like this

```
[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "personId": 80,
        "name": "note 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "personId": 5,
        "name": "note 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "personId": 80,
        "name": "note 3"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "personId": 80,
        "name": "note 4"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "personId": 42,
        "name": "note 5"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "personId": 80,
        "name": "note 6"
      }
    ]
```

and inside each `note` component I'm checking whether if the `personId` of `note` is present in my local array  of `persons`. If not I'm creating an api call to fetch the user and push it to my local array of `persons`.

**notes-card.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
if (this.localPersons.findIndex(item => item.id == this.note.personId) == -1) {
            this.subscription.add(this.companyService.getPerson(this.note.personId).subscribe(data => {
              this.person = data.body.results;
              if (this.localPersons.filter(e => e.id == data.body.results.id).length == 0) {
                this.localPersons.push(data.body.results);
                return
              } else {
                return
              }        
            }))
          }
    }
```

The application however is working fine but the api calls are getting called multiple times, is this because Is there a way to restrict api calls if the requesting content is already present in another instance?.

Comment: Can't you just make the calls onInit before you display the model in an `ngFor`? That's probably the easiest way to do so. You can even lazily set a boolean flag of `doneLoading` to false on the component creation and then set it `true` when you are done with your subscription code.

Comment: @user1274820 I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Well here's the thing - the parent component should have an array of everything. When you initialize the parent, it should check to see if people are missing from the `localPersons` array. It can make the calls and then set the `notes` element when it is done searching for missing people. If you try to do it in the child components, you'd have to pass some sort of reference and coordinate their calls and it's more complicated. The data should flow down to the children and the parent should handle that flow if you want them to work together to reduce repeated calls (if I'm understanding right).

Comment: I don't see where `localPersons` is passed to the `notes-card` component either, so I'm wondering how that's coordinated.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is the `localPersons` array should be controlled by the parent. The `notes-card.component` should not need to make calls. Just set the `notes` model in the parent when you've loaded everything it needs.

Comment: @user1274820 the localPersons is initiated when the application is booted up and it is stored in a centralized service file I'm taking it from the there but the problem is it is paginated so I will only get the first 10 persons that's why I use this approach

Comment: Can you not add an array of all people to your service and then use that subscription instead? Idk what your service looks like I'd have to see it, but if you have a list of people (even if it's paginated), you can go grab all the data for them. If you want to grab the people on each page change instead via API calls, then control those calls in the parent of the `notes-component`. Let the parent grab everything and then the children can just display the data. If you want the children to grab the data they need, then they should repeat the data grabs by design. Otherwise let service do it

Comment: "If not I'm creating an api call to fetch the user and push it to my local array of persons." - this is the issue. You should have your service do this instead of your component. That's probably the best way. Each component should request an ID from your service and if your service doesn't have that ID, it should go ahead and make the call. That way the service can coordinate the calls. If a request has already been made for an ID, you can return that same observable and every component gets updated when the data comes in without repeated calls regardless of how many are in `ngFor`.

Comment: @user1274820 thank you but I can't get all persons in a single go as the list may contain 1 - 10000 results.

Comment: That's fine - like I said in my last comment, your components should request an ID from your service. If your service doesn't have that in the array already, it should make a call to get it. If another component requests the same ID, your service is already making that call and can point them to the same observable. That way, one call will service as many components as are requesting the same ID.

Comment: @user1274820 I get it, thanks I will create a observable in service file and check there if it already exists there